# Initialize values of an array that is within a struct

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

I have a struct called `member`. Within `member` I have a `std::string` array called `months` that I would like to initialize to default values. This is how I am doing it currently:

```
template <typenameT>                                                                                               
struct member                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                   

    std::string months[12];                                                                                         
    std::string name;                                                                                               
    T hours_worked[12];                                                                                             
    T dues[12];                                                                                                     

    member() : months{"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"} {};    
};
```

However, whenever I compile I get this warning message:

```
warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
```

How can I do the initialization properly and get rid of this error message?

**Edit:**

I should of made my question more clear. I need compile this program on a older compiler and the `-std=c++0x` flag option will not be available to me. How can I do this correctly without using the flag.

Comment: It tells you exactly what to do, use `-std=c++0x` compilation flag.

Comment: @Als I would like to not have to set this flag. It seems like i am doing the initialization incorrectly. I have to run this on a different compiler where the `-std=c++0x` is not available.

Comment: i think this is a C++11 feature. your compiler must support C++11 for this code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you in the warning. Try adding `-std=c++0x` to your g++ arguments. If you want to be able to use this on an older compiler then you can't use initialiser lists the way you are doing.

Instead you could change member() to be something like

```
member()
{
  months[0] = "January";
  months[1] = "February";
  ...//etc
}
```

Comment: I would like to not have to set this flag. It seems like i am doing the initialization incorrectly. I have to run this on a different compiler where the `-std=c++0x` is not available

Comment: Thank you the syntax on how to do this is what I needed.